# Existe alguma diferença entre os códigos A e B abaixo?

Tags: jquery, click

**Codigo A**

```
$('#tantoFaz').on('click', function() {
 /* ....... */
});
```

**Codigo B**

```
$('#tantoFaz').click(function() {
 /* ....... */
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da maneira apresentada, não há diferença. De fato, a própria função `click` pode ser considerada como um atalho à função `on`, com o parâmetro `click`, com algumas ressalvas. A função `click` possui três variações:

```
.click(handler)
```

Em que `handler` é uma função que é executada a cada evento `click` do elemento. Esta variação é análoga a utilizar `.on("click", handler)`, como perguntado.

```
.click(eventData, handler)
```

A segunda variação recebe um parâmetro `eventData` a mais. O funcionamento desta variação também é análoga à utilização da função `on`, embora os dados informados em `eventData` serão passados como parâmetro à `handler` quando o evento for disparado.

```
.click()
```

A terceira variação, sem parâmetros, é a que deve-se tomar cuidado nesta comparação, pois sua utilização não é semelhante à função `on`. O que ela faz, de fato, é disparar o evento `click` do elemento em questão, executando todas as funções definidas pelas variações anteriores. Esta variação é análoga à `.trigger("click")`.

Portanto **não há diferença entre os códigos apresentados** na pergunta.

Referência: [Documentação oficial](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler)

Comment: +1! "Uma adição de contribuição que não vale a pena ser adicionada como resposta": Em casos de elementos criados dinamicamente, o evento `.click()` não irá funcionar como esperado, para isso teríamos que usar o `.on('click')`. [exemplo no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/7ds9devo/)